# Meaning "Haben sie etwas zum Schreiben?" in a phone-call context

Tags: meaning

**"Haben Sie etwas zum Schreiben?"** in a phone-call context means:

a) *Would you like to leave a note?*

b) *Do you have something close at hand to write down a note?*

c) something else (idiomatic expression)

The question popped up during an exercise and we are doubtful about the real meaning because of the following reasons:

- *have to* can be used in replacement of *must* (müssen)
- *Schreiben* has multiple meanings
- some idiomatic expression sometimes can't be found on a dictionary.

Comment: wo genau hast du aaaaaaaaaaaa gesagt?

Comment: Is that from a multiple choice test?

Comment: I don't think that question is of-topic. It can be related to some grammar topic that can bing confusion for a lerner:
- *haben zu* is often used instead of müssen

Comment: Robert - in some way yes. I was studing with other people and some gave different interpretations (a and b).

Comment: "Haben zu" is sometimes used in the sense of müssen. But there's a clear distinction between "Haben Sie zu schreiben?" and your sentence. And the word "zum" is obviously not part of "haben zu". Instead, it's a pretty simple sentence and I don't see where confusion arose. To make that question on-topic you would have to narrow that down.

Answer (score 4):

The caller asks you, if you have a piece of paper and a pencil which you can use to take some notes.
So sentence b) is right.

Comment: thank you very much! I was confused because the different meanings of "das Schreiben" and the "have zu" construct, that can also mean "have to"!